# Jacoco javaagent is not collecting the coverage data after tomcat shutdown

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, code-coverage, jacoco

-javaagent creates the **jacoco.exec** file during the tomcat start up and file is empty after tomcat shutdown.
Setting the JAVA_OPTS in **catalina.sh**

```
-javaagent:/opt/jacoco/jacoco_0.6.3_jars/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=/opt/logs/jacoco_it.exec,append=true,includes=com.*.
```

Comment: I think there is a dumponexit flag, but I seem to recall it defaults to true anyway. Are you shutting down tomcat clean or just killing it?

Comment: Tried shutting down by ./shutdown.sh script and also as service tomcat stop

Comment: That is usually the correct way. Try adding jmx=true and connect (say with jconsole) and see if you can interact with it while running (i.e. see if it is producing anything)

Comment: I tried setting Jmx and used jconsole.Once the application is loaded jconsole gives the number of the classes loaded.But Jacoco coverage report still the same. I am getting the following msg in catalina.out file( APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path) . Jacoco coverage is not collected because of this ?

Comment: no the apr should not be a player here. You should be able to find the IAgent at org.jacoco:type=Runtime and it does have a dump method to invoke via jmx